# Excel column headers export to csv

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv, xlsx

Just wandering how I can export excel files to csv while retaining the multicolumn headers?

I realize that csv does not support this however, I'm hoping that I can have the header name duplicated for every column that it goes over.

To illustrate, this is what I am currently getting

> a,,,b,,,c,,
>      1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
>      d1,d1,d1,d1,d1,d1,d1,d1,d1
>      d2,d2,d2,d2,d2,d2,d2,d2,d2

This is what I would like

> a,a,a,b,b,b,c,c,c
>      1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
>      d1,d1,d1,d1,d1,d1,d1,d1,d1
>      d2,d2,d2,d2,d2,d2,d2,d2,d2

I have searched to find an answer, however unless I'm searching the wrong term .... I can't seem to find much on it.

Solution doesn't have to be Microsoft .... can also be a linux solution.

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have exported your spreadsheet to `file1.csv`, as shown, do

```
#!/bin/sh
awk -F, -v OFS=, '
NR==1 {
        for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
                if ($i == "") $i = prev
                prev=$i
        }
    }
{ print }' < file1.csv > file2.csv
```

- `-F, -v OFS=,` sets `awk`’s input and output file separators to `,`.
- `NR==1` means “do the following on the first record (line/row) only”.
- The `for` loop looks at each field (cell) in the first row,
  and, if it’s blank, sets it equal to the preceding value.
- `{ print }` prints all records from `file1.csv` to `file2.csv`,
  with the first one being modified (as described above)
  and all others being passed through from input to output
  (so empty cells below the first row won’t be tampered with).